# Remove deployment permissions

Tags: apex

We are implementing our new Continuous Integration process and we want to avoid any manual deployment (via ant, SalesforceDX, etc). Is there any way to remove this permission??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference at the permission level between a CI/CI deploy and a manual one, but you can certainly restrict which *users* have the ability to perform deploys. Most likely, you have your CI process running on something like an "Integration User" or "Deployment User", which you can permission separately via a permission set.

You and your development and administration team may not find the solution palatable, though. In order to disable access to the Metadata API, you'll have to disable at least one of some [important permissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickstart_prereqs.htm):

> the “API Enabled” and “Modify All Data” [...] are required to access Metadata API calls.

There's also a beta "Modify Metadata" permission that would need to be disabled as well.

If your System Administrators are running on the standard profile, you'll have to create a custom one to change those permissions.

There is also a permission for Deploy Change Sets.